# Why infinite digest error while compiling html text (from db) which contains a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-directive

- I have a controller (say SampleController), in which it gets data (as following html text) from $http service & assigning it to $scope.htmlText

  ```
  <p>This is some content text
       <span class='sampleClassDirective' pid='1'>P1 Value</span> 
       some other text 
       <span class='sampleClassDirective' pid='2'>P2 Value</span> 
  some more text </p>
  ```
- I want to render this html text in a view. As it is html text, I can use ng-html-bind directive to render the html-text as it is.
- but i want to compile the html text, so that directives inside html text can get their templates if any
- **Actual problem starts here**
- As you can see above content has some tags with class="sampleClassDirective"
- I have a directive with name as "sampleClassDirective"
- This directive uses ui.bootstrap popover component in its template

  ```
  angular.module('app').dirctive('sampleClassDirective', 
      function(){
         return {
             restrict:'C',
             transclude:true,
             template:'<span uib-popover="This is pid">'+
                         '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'+
                      '</span>'
         }
      });
  ```
- Now, I want to compile the whole htmlText which I got in sampleController, so that the "sampleClassDirective" & "uib-popover" both gets compiled.
- So In view I gave

  ```
  <div id='htmlContent' ng-bind-html='render()'></div>
  ```
- In sampleController

  ```
  $scope.render = function(){
      var elm = angular.element(htmlText);
      // compiling each directive
      var classDirectives = $(elm).find(".sampleClassDirective");
      for(var i=0, iMax=classDirectives.length; i<iMax; i++){
          $(elm).find(".sampleClassDirective")[i].append($compile(classDirectives[i])($scope));
      }
      // or can we compile all htmlText at once?
      // elm = $compile(elm)($scope)

      return $sce.trustAsHtml($(elm).html());
  }
  ```
- **Question : **
- While it is getting compiled, why I'm getting $rootScope infinite $digest error & it is aborting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting an executed function on an an angular directive typically screws with the digest cycle. I would try putting the output of render on a different variable and adding that to ng-bind html, e.g

```
$scope.renderedOutput = $scope.render();
<div id='htmlContent' ng-bind-html='renderedOutput'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you... This is clean & straight forward..Do you have any documentation regarding this, I wanted to know more about it.

Comment: I just figured this out from experience, when I put a console log in a function and it prints 200 times. I'm not exactly sure why angular freaks out when you execute a function on the html. I would just google "angular digest cycle" to learn more

Comment: Thank you, it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

While don't you do this

```
$('#htmlContent').html(htmlText)
$compile($('#htmlContent'))($scope)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me try, I will get back to this soon

Comment: It is working.. Thank you, but in this example I have only one '#htmlContent' but in my actual app, I have this div inside ng-repeat, so by the time it is executing, the html element is not available. So I have enclosed in $timeout to push down to the event-stack. It has getting rendered but not working fully. By the way, thanks to give me a starting point. I will check.

Comment: Then I think you can create a directive and put it inside your ng-repeat.